# What is the order in which Linux resolves DNS?

Tags: linux, dns

What is the order in which Linux resolves `DNS` ? Do I read `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, then read `hosts`, then go to `/etc/resolv.conf` DNS, and then go to network connection `DNS` ?

I know very little about `DNS` and would be grateful for any answer that could help me understand

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order in which Linux resolves DNS is *very configurable*.

First read the `hosts:` line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. The keywords on that line specify the order in which various sources are used.

The set of keywords available depends on your Linux distribution.
The classic ones are:

- `files` tells the system to read `/etc/hosts`
- `dns` tells the system to use the DNS servers specified in `/etc/resolv.conf`. (New systems using `systemd-resolved` might be working towards eventually making this obsolete.)
- `nis` or `nisplus` would refer to the centrally managed hosts table of the NIS/NIS+ system (practically obsolete)
- `compat` is like `files`, but also allows the old NIS extension syntax that was used before `/etc/nsswitch.conf` existed. (practically obsolete)

Modern systems may have new keywords added, like:

- `resolve` tells the system to use `systemd-resolved`. If this keyword is present, use the `resolvectl` command to view the actual DNS server settings. If the `dns` keyword is not also present, the `/etc/resolv.conf` file may be **completely ignored**.
- `mdns4_minimal`, `mdns6_minimal` or `mdns_minimal` tell the system to attempt to resolve short hostnames or long names of the form `shortname.local` by sending a mDNS packet to the appropriate multicast address, using IPv4, IPv6 or both, respectively. The multicast address is 224.0.0.251 for IPv4 and ff02::fb for IPv6, and the destination port is 5353/UDP in both cases. If other systems in the same network have `avahi-daemon` or another mDNS responder configured, this might allow you to use hostnames in your local network segment without setting up a real DNS server or maintaining `/etc/hosts` files on every system.
- `myhostname` allows the system to always successfully resolve its own hostname, even if no `/etc/hosts` or DNS servers are configured, and no network connections are present.
- `mymachines` allows the system to automatically resolve the hostnames of virtual machines that have been set up using `systemd-machined.service`

There may be other keywords, as the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` system can be extended by providing shared libraries that implement the Name Service Switch API, named like `libnss_<keyword>.so*`.

---

If you see the line `nameserver 127.0.0.53` in `/etc/resolv.conf`, this is also a sign that `systemd-resolved` is in use and you should use `resolvectl` to check the actual DNS settings instead.

Most programs use the hostname resolution functions of the C standard library (usually `glibc`), but some programs that are either very old or are designed for DNS diagnostics will read `/etc/resolv.conf` directly.

By using the keyword `resolve` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, the hostname resolution functions of the C standard library are routed directly to `systemd-resolved`, and having `nameserver 127.0.0.53` in `/etc/resolv.conf` also redirects any old/diagnostic programs to use the local `systemd-resolved`.

The `dns` keyword and `/etc/resolv.conf` are being considered for replacement because they don't really support the concept of connection-specific DNS servers: they have a built-in assumption that all DNS servers know all the same things, so if one DNS server says something does not exist, they assume there is no reason to ask a second opinion from a different DNS server.

`systemd-resolved` allows for connection-specific DNS servers to be configured, and also allows directing queries about specific domains to connection-specific DNS servers.

(Technically, if a DNS server responds "the record you asked for does not exist", it is *a valid answer, not an error* - although it might not be the kind of answer you wanted. Only responses like "I am unable to answer that question" or "I am not allowed to tell you" would be errors.)